# What happens if lease is signed but landlord doesnt want me, do I still have to pay the realtor fee?

Tags: landlord, tenant, rent, lease, new-jersey

I live in Dumont, NJ. I'm about to sign a lease with a landlord and I also have Section 8. I haven't moved in yet; To finalize the rent payment to the landlord, there must be a HAP contract signed by the 3 parties in which I pay a portion and Section 8 pays a portion of the rent after me giving the executed lease (landlord+tenant only).If Section 8 doesnt go through with the contract, I will guess the landlord wont want me. Will I still have to pay the 1 month Broker fee since nothing was finalized/signed? Broker section in Lease states for me to pay the fee "upon signing the lease." I want to wait to pay it until everything is finalized. I asked for broker to put "upon signing HAP contract" instead, but she seems dismissive to my written request.

Your guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What are *the exact* terms (if any) of the contract in regard to (1) the broker fee, and (2) the landlord's decision?

Comment: Update: broker did add fee will be given upon signing HAP contract. For the sake of time, I cant write the entire contract. However, it states that the fee would be paid upon signing the Section 8 contract and when all the paperwork is finalized with Section 8. It doesnt mention anything about conditions with the broker and landlord. What is your opinion if I or Section 8 dont want to follow through? Will I owe them or not even though nothing was finalized? thanks in advance.

Comment: "*For the sake of time, I cant write the entire contract.*" You were never expected to write the *entire* contract, but just two portions that seem relevant to your question. Just saying that "*It doesnt mention anything about conditions with the broker and landlord*" is inconclusive as to item (2) because it is unclear to us whether or not your statement refers to conditions *only between* broker and landlord. Chances are the broker fee will be due once everyone is on board by signing the lease *and* the HAP contract, but the lack of clarity in your question precludes an assertive assessment.